# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.Reason given for failure:CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am getting this error when I hit the submit button in the login form:

`Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. CSRF token missing or incorrect.`

setting.py

```python
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

view.py

```python
def contact_us(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        con_name = request.POST['con_name']
        con_email = request.POST['con_email']
        con_company = request.POST['con_company']
        inquiry = request.POST['inquiry']
        con_message = request.POST['con_message']
        #context = RequestContext(request)
        #context_dict={'con_name':con_name}
        #context_dict.update(csrf(request))
        return render(request, 'contact_us.html', {'con_name':con_name})

    else:
        return render(request, 'contact_us.html',{})
```

contact_us.html

```html
<form id="contact-form" action="{% url 'contact_us' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="contact-form">
    <div class="contact-input">
      <div class="contact-inner">
        <input name="con_name" type="text" placeholder="Name *">
      </div>
      <div class="contact-inner">
        <input name="con_email" type="email" placeholder="Email *">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-inner">
      <input name="con_company" type="text" placeholder="Company">
    </div>
    <div class="contact-select">
      <div class="form-item contact-inner">
        <span class="inquiry">
          <select name="inquiry" class="select-item">
              <option value="Your inquiry for">Your inquiry for</option>
              <option value="General Information Request">General Information Request</option>
              <option value="Partner Relations">Public Relations</option>
              <option value="Digital Marketing">Digital Marketing</option>
              <option value="Influencer Marketing">Influencer Marketing</option>
              <option value="Brand Creation">Brand Creation</option>
              <option value="Careers">Careers</option>
              <option value="Brand Creation">Web Development</option>
              <option value="Others">Others</option>
          </select>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-inner contact-message">
      <textarea name="con_message" placeholder="Please describe what you need."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="submit-btn mt-20">
      <button class="ht-btn ht-btn-md" type="submit">Send message</button>
      <p class="form-messege"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I am new to Django and most web development and I just cannot find the problem here. What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass RequestContext in render_to_response for csrf_token

For this : (views.py)

```
from django.template import RequestContext

...

return render_to_response('fileupload/upload.html', {'form':
```

c['UploadFileForm']},  RequestContext(request))

This passes the token for csrf to the template.

Visit this [Link](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.x/ref/contrib/csrf.html) also, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem.It got resolved when i put "{% csrf_token %}" before each input tags when they weren't together or separated by any other tags.